# pandas selection from a specific year

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to `select` the following data using `pandas` for Python 2.7 from the web page (http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/202_EN.htm) starting from the year 1991 to 2000. somebody please can help me how I can write the code. Thanks!

```
    datum  m_ta m_tax     m_taxd m_tan     m_tand
------- ----- ----- ---------- ----- ----------
1901-01  -4.7   5.0 1901-01-23 -12.2 1901-01-10
1901-02  -2.1   3.5 1901-02-06  -7.9 1901-02-15
1901-03   5.8  13.5 1901-03-20   0.6 1901-03-01
1901-04  11.6  18.2 1901-04-10   7.4 1901-04-23
1901-05  16.8  22.5 1901-05-31  12.2 1901-05-05
1901-06  21.0  24.8 1901-06-03  14.6 1901-06-17
1901-07  22.4  27.4 1901-07-30  16.9 1901-07-04
1901-08  20.7  25.9 1901-08-01  14.7 1901-08-29
1901-09  15.9  19.9 1901-09-01  11.8 1901-09-09
1901-10  12.6  17.9 1901-10-04   8.3 1901-10-31
1901-11   4.7  11.1 1901-11-14  -0.2 1901-11-26
1901-12   4.2   8.4 1901-12-22  -1.4 1901-12-07
1902-01   3.4   7.5 1902-01-25  -2.2 1902-01-15
1902-02   2.8   6.6 1902-02-09  -2.8 1902-02-06
1902-03   5.3  13.3 1902-03-22  -3.5 1902-03-13
1902-04  10.5  15.8 1902-04-21   6.1 1902-04-08
1902-05  12.5  20.6 1902-05-31   8.5 1902-05-10
1902-06  18.5  23.8 1902-06-30  14.4 1902-06-19
....
```

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Or you need select data from `1901` to `2000` ?

Comment: Yes, I need to select the whole data from 1991 to 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for selecting data by column `datum`:

```
#convert column datum to period
df['datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datum']).dt.to_period('M')
#convert columns to datetime
df['m_taxd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['m_taxd'])
df['m_tand'] = pd.to_datetime(df['m_tand'])
```

```
print df.datum.dt.year
0     1901
1     1901
2     1901
3     1901
4     1901
5     1901
6     1901
7     1901
8     1901
9     1901
10    1901
11    1901
12    1902
13    1902
14    1902
15    1902
16    1902
17    1902
Name: datum, dtype: int64
#change 1901 to 2000
print df[df.datum.dt.year <= 1901]
     datum  m_ta  m_tax     m_taxd  m_tan     m_tand
0  1901-01  -4.7    5.0 1901-01-23  -12.2 1901-01-10
1  1901-02  -2.1    3.5 1901-02-06   -7.9 1901-02-15
2  1901-03   5.8   13.5 1901-03-20    0.6 1901-03-01
3  1901-04  11.6   18.2 1901-04-10    7.4 1901-04-23
4  1901-05  16.8   22.5 1901-05-31   12.2 1901-05-05
5  1901-06  21.0   24.8 1901-06-03   14.6 1901-06-17
6  1901-07  22.4   27.4 1901-07-30   16.9 1901-07-04
7  1901-08  20.7   25.9 1901-08-01   14.7 1901-08-29
8  1901-09  15.9   19.9 1901-09-01   11.8 1901-09-09
9  1901-10  12.6   17.9 1901-10-04    8.3 1901-10-31
10 1901-11   4.7   11.1 1901-11-14   -0.2 1901-11-26
11 1901-12   4.2    8.4 1901-12-22   -1.4 1901-12-07
```